# Все ли запятые расставлены правильно?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*А признать, что он не прав, не хочет.

Человеку это не нравится, а говорить ему, что это красиво, не надо.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*А признать, **что он не прав**, не хочет.*
Знаки в сложноподчинённом предложении расставлены правильно: придаточное предложение (что он не прав) находится внутри главного (А признать не хочет), поэтому  оно выделяется запятыми с двух сторон.
Правило:
если придаточное предложение стоит в середине главного, то придаточное предложение отделяется от главного с двух сторон.

*Человеку это не нравится, а говорить ему, **что это красиво**, не надо.*
Странное предложение, искусственное какое-то, тем не менее знаки в нем расставлены верно (несмотря на то, что дважды повторяется слово "это").
Если изъять придаточное, то смысл предложения (без контекста) теряется:
*Человеку это не нравится, а говорить ему не надо.*

[Сложноподчинённые предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/735-21_obschaya_harakteristika_slozhnopodchinennyh_predlozhenii.html)